# flutter - flutter provider not updating the ui

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-provider, flutter-getx

I am working on an e-commerce project. In that project, I am using the `provider package` to manage states in flutter. In development mode provider updates the UI but When I build the apk using `flutter build apk --release` it does not update the UI.

I don't understand why is it not updating the UI instantly.

*cart provider*

```
class CartProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  int _counter = 0;
  int get counter => _counter;
  double _totalPrice = 0.0;
  double get totalPrice => _totalPrice;
 
  int getCounter() {
    final box = Boxes.getData();
    print(box.length);
    notifyListeners();
    return box.length;
  }
}
```

*adding product to hive db as well as updating the cart count using provider*

```
 var data = ProductModel(
                                name: widget.productTitle.toString(),
                                price: totalController.text,
                                quantity: widget.productqty.toString(),
                                unit: widget.productunit[0]['unit'],
                                agentId: widget.agentId,
                                menuId: widget.menuId,
                                productId: widget.productId,
                                showunitlist: widget.showunitlist.toString(),
                                serviceid: widget.serviceid,
                                unitlist: list,
                                originalprice: '');

                            cart.addTotalPrice(
                                double.parse(totalController.text.toString()));
                            cart.addCounter();
                            final box = Boxes.getData();
                            box.add(data);
                            data.save();
```

*appbar*

```
 appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Cart"),
        actions: [
          Row(
            children: [
              InkWell(
                onTap: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => const CartList()));
                },
                child: Center(
                  child: Badge(
                    badgeContent: Consumer(
                      builder: ((context, value, child) {
                        return Text(
                          cart.getCounter().toString(),
                          style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                        );
                      }),
                    ),
                    child: const Icon(Icons.shopping_cart),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
```

Comment: Did you add INTERNET permissions to AndroidManifest.xml?

Comment: @rrttrr Yes sir. But when I navigate to another page the cart count gets updated !

Answer (score 0):

Connect your Provider class with the Consumer widget as you see below:

```
Consumer<CartProvider>(
                  builder: ((context, cartProvider , child) {});
```

Comment: not working sir.